# Send request in certain date and time in django-cron

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cron

I want to send one POST request or GET request in a certain date and certain time say date is 1st feb and time is 2:00pm then request should automatically be sent at that date and time. Those date and time are stored in the database. What should be the approach for that? 
I tried using django-cron but it runs only when i type `python3 manage.py runcrons`. i want it to run when server is running i.e after every 5 mins.

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. However there is a DateTimeField which you can add to your model.

Comment: the request should be called automatically without being called from front end at certain time. how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i followed [this](https://django-cron.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html) document. I previously didn't follow

```
> crontab -e
*/5 * * * * source /home/ubuntu/.bashrc && source /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/bin/activate && python /home/ubuntu/work/your-project/src/manage.py runcrons > /home/ubuntu/cronjob.log
```

now it is working properly.